# Display the following AJAX in a blank/new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to display the part which comes with the AJAX code in a new or blank page, without getting the requested url under the "old" html code on the same page.

```
d$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#bestello").submit(function() {
            if($("#nn").val() == "" || $("#vn").val() == "" || $("#strt").val() == ""){
                $("#response").html("Bitte f&uuml;llen Sie alle Felder aus!");
            } else {
                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: "nn=" + $("#nn").val() + "&vn=" + $("#vn").val() + "&strt=" + $("#strt").val(),
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#response").html(msg);
                    }
                });

            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Everything after the else or $.ajax({ should be displayed in a blank/new page. 
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why then use AJAX in the first place? Just submit the form normally, and use its `target` attribute to direct the response into a new window/tab or a previously opened one.

Answer (score 1):

**You are looking for popup functions.**

Place the following code inside your success function

```
var w = window.open('', '', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
w.document.write(msg);
w.document.close(); // needed for chrome and safari
```

Comment: When I add your solution i don´t get the alert or warning in response -div when i dont write the full formular

Comment: Well this solution should not alter the warning case. Please give me the link of your webpage so that I can do further tests

Answer (score 0):

Rather than submitting the form with ajax, allow the form to be submitted using its native functionality. Add the attributes `target='_blank' action='test.php' method='post'` to the form so that it will submit to test.php using post and open in a new tab/window.

You can still use javascript to validate the form. Your code would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bestello").submit(function() {
        if($("#nn").val() == "" || $("#vn").val() == "" || $("#strt").val() == ""){
            $("#response").html("Bitte f&uuml;llen Sie alle Felder aus!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

This will validate the form with javascript and only allow it to submit if it passes validation. (As a side note, you should make sure that you do some server side validation as well).